# Centering plot in rmarkdown pdf displays latex code in output (\begin{center}) latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rmarkdown

I'm new to latex and rmarkdown. I am trying to center a plotly chart and I have already tried fig.align = "center" and nothing happens, if to this command I add fig.show = 'hold', the plot is centered but the \begin{center} code is added after the plot image. I tried to add latex code directly before the chunk (\ begin {center}) and \ end {center} after, but it still appears in the pdf output visible latex code. Please I don't no what happen with this.[image]

This is my code

```
a <- list(
  autotick = FALSE,
  ticks = "outside",
  tick0 = 0,
  dtick = 1,
  ticklen = 0,
  tickwidth = 1,
  tickcolor = toRGB("blue")
)
avlbty<-plot_ly(df_merged, x = ~daytime, y = ~Availability, color = ~Series,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tozeroy', width =700, height = 350)
avlbty<-avlbty %>% 
  layout(title = "Availability by Service",yaxis = a,
         xaxis=list(title='Date'),font=f, margin = list(l=50, r=50, b=0, t=30, pad=0))
avlbty
```

Comment: It is impossible to replicate this as we don't have access to `df_merged` or other items. Please produce a MWE.

Comment: my full code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618432/centering-plot-in-rmarkdown-pdf-displays-latex-code-in-output-begincenter @oliversm

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem, with fig.align='center' nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Export figure and then include it again

In a similar manner to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269138/5134817) to [Plotly as png in knitr/rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268152/plotly-as-png-in-knitr-rmarkdown)
 the current hack is to export the figure and then load in the produced file. As a small example (which you could adapt) there is

````
---
title: "Diamond prices"
author: "Oliver"
date: "6^th^ May 2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{cleveref}
fontsize: 12pt
always_allow_html: yes
---

# Making a plot

```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
options(shiny.testmode = TRUE)
library(knitr) 
library(plotly)
data("diamonds")
```


```{r , echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
fig <- plot_ly(diamonds, x = ~carat, y = ~price, type="scatter", mode="markers", color = ~clarity, width =200, height = 150)
orca(fig, file="diamonds.png")
```

![\label{fig:fig_prices_of_diamonds}The price of diamonds depnds on their size.](diamonds.png)

We can see in \Cref{fig:fig_prices_of_diamonds} how expensive diamonds can be.
````

which produces

[image]

## Option 2: Use webshot

Based on comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825213/5134817) to [Change output width of plotly chart size in R Markdown PDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52649044/5134817) an alternative is to capture the image automatically using wesbot. Simply run the following once in the R console to install webshot (and PhantomJS which webshot in turn uses):

```
install.packages('webshot')
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

One you have this you can adapt the above example to use instead:

````
```{r fig:fig_prices_of_diamonds, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:fig_prices_of_diamonds}The prices of diamonds increases perhaps?"}
plot_ly(diamonds, x = ~carat, y = ~price, type="scatter", mode="markers", color = ~clarity, width =400, height = 250)
```

We can see in \Cref{fig:fig_prices_of_diamonds} how expensive diamonds can be.
````

which is much cleaner code.

Comment: But in your example, the chart occupies the entire page horizontally, so it is not centered. In my case, I want a plotly chart with smaller dimensions and horizontally align centered.

Comment: It only seems to fill the whole page and be justified as the figure is big. If I make the figure smaller it centers. I will update the answer shortly to show this.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try

Comment: @Liliana, I have added an alternative using Webshot where some parameters such as width and height can also be adjusted.

Comment: thanks again for helping me